# Ruby Selenium Firefox only downloading to ~/Downloads on MacOS

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ruby-on-rails-6

I am having trouble getting Selenium to download files to the specified folder on MacOS.

Running:

- Ruby 3.0.1p64
- Rails 6.1.3.1
- selenium-webdriver 4.0.0beta3

This is my current code, which has attempts to change the directory in four places (any help much appreciated):

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'fileutils'
Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :info

@download_dir = File.join(Dir.pwd, "lib/forecastdownloads")
FileUtils.mkdir_p @download_dir     # Create the folder if missing

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.dir'] = @download_dir
profile['browser.download.default_directory'] = @download_dir

options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(profile: profile)
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_preference('download.directory_upgrade', true)
options.add_preference('download.folderList', 2)
options.add_preference('download.prompt_for_download', false)
options.add_preference('download.dir', @download_dir)
options.add_preference('download.default_directory', @download_dir)
options.add_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv')

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, capabilities: options
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10 # seconds
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)
driver.get "https://...[the webpage]"

element = wait.until { driver.find_element(:class, "buttons-excel") }
element.click
driver.quit
```

With the above code, files are downloading to the regular `~/Downloads` folder instead of `@download_dir`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the setting for `download.dir`.

Instead of `File.join(Dir.pwd, "lib/forecastdownloads")`, it should be:

```
profile['browser.download.dir'] = Dir.pwd + '/forecastdownloads'
```